# Redirect 301 de un dominio a otro

Tags: .htaccess

Necesito hacer desde el htaccess un redirect de un dominio/carpeta a otro dominio/carpeta

Algo así (pero no funciona):

```
Redirect 301 http://staging.2020.test/carpeta http://staging.com/svn/
```

ocurre que si lo pongo de esta manera me funciona:

```
Redirect 301 /carpeta http://staging.com/svn/
```

pero como comparten el htaccess ambos dominios debería ponerle algún condicional.

Así está hoy mi htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(admin|fonts|img|images|mobile|swf|static|upload|votacionVotar|ext_admin|servicioderadio) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(css|js) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*.php) - [L]
RewriteRule ^minify_css/fonts/(.*)$ css/fonts/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ _include/views/sitemap/sitemap.xml.php [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
#RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ main.php?path=$1$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: deberian de ser dos proyecto distintos no deben compartir nada aun cuando hagan lo mismo

Comment: No, es justo lo contrario, es el mismo proyecto que se comparte en dos dominios, mismo proyecto mismo servidor pero dos dominios que apuntan al mismo